# Spring Cloud DataFlow: Getting payload as List<Map>

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

Using Spring Cloud DataFlow 1.3.0.M2 with Spring Cloud Stream Starters Celsius.M1.

I have two processors. First produces a `List<Map>` that is supposed to be consumed by the other. Here is simplified code.

```
// Processor 1
@StreamListener(Processor.INPUT)
@SendTo(Processor.OUTPUT)
// Note: had Object instead of List<> as the return, hoped perhaps using a
// specific type would help, but no difference.
public List<Map<String, Object>> process(final @Payload MyPojo payload) {
    final List<Map<String, Object>> results = worker.doWork(payload);
    LOG.debug("Returning " + results.size() + " objects");
    return results;
}

// Processor 2
@StreamListener(Processor.INPUT)
@SendTo(Processor.OUTPUT)
public Object process(final @Payload List<Map<String, Object>> payload) {
    LOG.debug("Received " + payload.size() + " objects");
    final List<Map<String, Object>> results = worker.moreWork(payload);
    return results;
}
```

I am deploying these two processors in a pipeline using the SCDF shell:

```
<source> | otherProcessors | processor1 | processor2 | log
```

The debug message for Processor 1 says it has 2 objects in the List. Processor 2's debug message says it received 40 objects (each map has 20 key=value pairs) - it appears the two maps got flattened into one list of key=value pairs.

I have debug logging enabled for `org.spring.integration` and the message appears to have a list of maps format (this is from Processor 2):

```
preSend on channel 'input', message: GenericMessage 
  [payload=[{"m1key1":"val1","m1key2":"val2",...,"m1key20":"val20"},
   {"m2key1":"val1","m2key2":"val2",...,"m2key20":"val20"}], headers={..}]
```

I'd like Processor 2 to receive the 2 maps produced by Processor 1. I wonder if this is something related to generic types. Can someone point me towards the configuration to make this happen?

---- Update for Artem's comments ----

Processor 1 has this in its `application.properties` file:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.content-type=application/json
```

I had also tried modifying the stream definition like this but it didn't seem to make a difference:

```
<source> | otherProcessors | processor1 --outputType=application/json | processor2 --inputType=application/json | log
```

Comment: You know that doesn't look like JSON, but indeed as `GenericMessage.toString()`. Would you mind to share `headers` you have there on the matter? At least `contentType`

Comment: And yes, what is `input/output` configuration do you have on those processors? I mean `binding` setting

Comment: Updated post to answer questions, Artem, thank you.

Comment: OK. Thanks for the update. How does it work if you don't use any JSON in between? I mean how is it with the standard Java (de)serialization?

Comment: Removing the contentType settings lets the conversion work as expected. (Header in processor2's inbound message is `contentType=application/x-java-object;type=java.util.ArrayList`.) This solves my problem, thanks! I'm still curious as to why the contentType of JSON didn't work though, and what I would need to change if I had to make it work for some reason. Link to docs gratefully accepted; I searched before asking but may not have found the right section. I'm learning a bunch of new tools at once and sometimes just don't know which tool docs holds the answer I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you actually stumbled upon a bug :)

This has been fixed on the 2.0 branch, which is a bit unstable for the moment considering it's a snapshot.

Things should be better once we release in a few days.

Team is discussing the path forward on back porting the fix to 1.3 line.

Comment: Great, in a way. I feel better now, was wondering what the heck I missed in the config, and just when I thought I was starting to understand too. :) At least I provided a fairly small test case for the team to reproduce the problem and fix it! Thanks for the update!